# Haskell program aborts with "loop" but I think it shouldn't

Tags: haskell

I have this Haskell code which when compiled with GHC and run, aborts with a loop detected.

```
data Foo = Foo ()
 deriving (Eq,Show)

type Foop = Foo -> ((),Foo)

noOp :: Foop
noOp st = ((),st)

someOp :: Foop
someOp st@(Foo x) = ((),st)

(<+>) :: Foop -> Foop -> Foop
(<+>) f g st = let ((_,st'),(_,st'')) = ((f st),(g st')) in ((),st'')

main = print $ (noOp <+> someOp) $ Foo ()
```

I think it shouldn't, and here are some modifications. Each of them makes the loop go away:

- change `data Foo` to `newtype Foo`
- change `(noOp <+> someOp)` to `(someOp <+> noOp)`
- remove the deconstruction `@(Foo x)`

Is this a bug in GHC or is it my lack of understanding the evaluation process?

Answer (score 12):

- Pattern match `(_, _)` demands WHNF of `(f st, g st')`. Easy.
- Pattern match `(_, (_,_))` demands WHNF of `g st'`. Here's the problem, because `g` is strict, hence it first needs `st'` in WHNF too. The runtime finds `st'` in the pattern `((_,st'), (_,_))`, so before it can actually traverse down into `st'` it needs to WHNF both of the tuples. Because `g` is strict however, this first requires `st'`... and so on.

If you match the result of `g` with a lazy irrefutable pattern

```
(<+>) f g st = let ((_,st'), ~(_,st'')) = (f st, g st') in ((),st'')
```

then the problem goes away, because this is evaluated thus:

- Pattern match `(_, _)` demands WHNF of `(f st, g st')`. Easy.
- Pattern match `(_, ~(_,_))` demands nothing more for the time being.
- Pattern match `((_,st'), ~(_,_))` demands WHNF of `f st`. Fortunately, we can fulfill this, because `st` does not depend on the pattern.
- Now we've satisfied the pattern match, the runtime can already proceed with the `in ((),st'')`. Only at this point is the irrefutable pattern `~(_,st'')` forced, but this is now not a problem anymore because `st'` is available here, so it's just a matter of computing `g` once.

The fixes you've tried all amount to making `g` non-strict:

> remove the deconstruction `@(Foo _)`

Without that, `g` doesn't really need to look at its argument to construct the result skeleton, i.e. the tuple match `(_,st'')` can then succeed without first requiring WHNF of `st'`.

> change `data Foo` to `newtype Foo`

This has the effect that the `Foo` constructor doesn't actually exist at runtime, so there's nothing that the pattern `st@(Foo _)` would force.

> change `noOp <+> someOp` to `someOp <+> noOp`

As I said, the loop only comes about because `g` is strict. If you put `f` in its position, which is not strict, then there's no problem.

Comment: Thanks, this might be a good step towards helping me to understand it :-) However I still don't understand why it can't first WHNF the left tuple to get `st'` and then the right tuple to get `st''`? I can see that WHNFing the right tuple requires WHNFing the left tuple but I don't see the problem with WHNFing the left tuple.

Comment: You can first WHNF the left tuple, but it doesn't give you `st'`. It only gives you `(_,~st')`, as it were.

Comment: In the specific case, `(_,st') = f st = noOp st = ((),st)`, so `st' = st = Foo ()` which would also satisfy the strictness of `g` alias `someOp`. Shouldn't this be possible to compute?

Comment: `let Pat (Pet x) (Pot y) = bar in baz` is evaluated as ``let Pat ξ υ = bar in ξ `seq` υ `seq` (let Pet x = ξ; Pet y = υ in baz)``. So `υ` is forced before `x` actually gets into being.

Comment: I think that doesn't explain why forcing `υ` wouldn't force `x`. What you say makes it sound (to me) like it should be a statically invalid expression.

Comment: `x` doesn't _exist_ at the point where the runtimes tries to force `υ`.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a bug -- you just found a tricky corner of the lazy pattern semantics. Let me present a simpler case:

```
> data Id a = Id a
> let Id a = undefined ; Id b = Id 3 in b
3
> let (Id a, Id b) = (undefined, Id 3) in b
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

The difference is that the first `let` is equivalent to

```
case undefined of
  ~(Id a) -> case Id 3  of
               ~(Id b) -> b
```

while the second is

```
case (undefined, Id 3) of
  ~(Id a, Id b) -> b
```

The first will not evaluate the `undefined` unless `a` is demanded (which does not happen).

The second will pattern match against both patterns `Id a` and `Id b` as soon as **either** variable is demanded, forcing both `undefined` and `Id 3` in the process.

Note that, because of this issue, the patterns `~(K1 (K2 x) (K3 y))`, `~(K1 ~(K2 x) (K3 y))`, `~(K1 (K2 x) ~(K3 y))` and `~(K1 ~(K2 x) ~(K3 y))` have different semantics.

To fix your code, try

```
let (~(_,st'),~(_,st'')) = ((f st),(g st')) in ((),st'')
```

or

```
let (_,st') = f st ; (_,st'') = g st' in ((),st'')
```

Comment: It's sufficient to use one irrefutable match: `let ((_,st'), ~(_,st'')) = (f st, g st')`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Isn't `st''` the first thing which is demanded? `let ... in ((), st'')`. Further, `g` could be non-strict in the general case.

Comment: Thanks, that was insightful. Now in my code there is no `undefined` and I still don't see why it loops. Could you also shed some light on that?

Comment: @χ: what's important is that the result of `g st'` is not forced to WHNF (which requires `st'` to be WHNF first, if `g` is strict) before evaluating the variables matched within the tuples (including `st'`).

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm stubborn tonight :-) Take `f _ = undefined` and `g _ = ()`. With only one lazy pattern, it should diverge because the laziness of `g` is nullified by `f` being called anyway. This is probably not the case with `g` as used in the OP, still I thought the second lazy pattern could be useful in the general case.

Comment: @JoSo Briefly put, there is a circular dependency between `st',st''` and `f st, g st'` since `st'` occurs in both. This makes the definition recursive, essentially. The patterns, as they are, force both `f st` and `g st'` before defining (loosely speaking) `st', st''`, triggering a loop. leftaroundabout explained in his answer at the top in more detail.

Comment: Well, with `f _ = undefined` you create a new problem that's somewhat unrelated to the original question. I wouldn't make that other pattern lazy without good reason – lazy patterns tend to be pretty bad for performance. (Indeed your other proposal, `let (_,st') = f st ; (_,st'') = g st' in ((),st'')`, is IMO a better solution than anything with lazy patterns.)